# 404 page with file name query

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

How can I make a 404 php page with the 404'd file name in the link, example would be:

```
http://website.com/WrongPageName.html
```

would go to

```
 http://website.com/404.php?page=WrongPageName.html
```

Comment: That's a feature of your HTTP server, not your PHP installation. Which one are you using? Apache? Lighttpd? Nginx? IIS? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry did abit of research after soulmerge told me its a feature in my http, so i found out

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

then i used htaccess to go to a 404 file which would echo that out, the rest of the work is simple.

Answer (score 0):

I use this syntax! Usually works!

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<script>window.location.href='404.php?page='+window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1];</script>"
```